# How to place an closing button on a tab, using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating dynamics tabs using ReactJS and Material UI, but I wonder how to place a functional closing tab button directly on the tab.

I mean this:

[image]

And by the way, is there any way to place the icon side by side with the text?

Comment: Try using `iconLabelWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }` to make the icon and text side by side

Comment: This would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508683/function-inside-material-ui-tabs-not-firing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```
<Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Tab label={
          <span>
                    {'Active'}
                    <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => { handle() }}>
                      <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </span>
        } />
        <Tab label="Disabled" disabled />
        <Tab label="Active" />
      </Tabs>
```

Comment: => Yields an 'invalid DOM nesting' warning, "button cannot be a descendent of button".

Comment: Additionally, I'm getting `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'children' is not supported. Please remove it.` with just the `<span>` in there.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer worked great.
To remove all warnings you can add **component="span"** to **IconButton**

```
<Tab key={key}  label={
    <span> 
        {tab.Name}
        <IconButton size="small" component="span" onClick={() => { alert("Closing this tab..."); }}>
            <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </span>
    }
/>
```

Comment: better solution to avoid the warning and error. Thanks